# How to know which processes are using the specified file

Tags: powershell

The system will give an error when I try to delete it. Of course I know the command `Stop-Process` can help me kill the process. But I don't know which processes are using it. Can anybody tell me how the find the processes which are using the specified file?

PS:this is my powershell version:

[image]

Comment: Did you do any research at all? [Weekend Scripter: Determine Process that Locks a File](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/12/01/weekend-scripter-determine-process-that-locks-a-file/) and [PowerShell script to check an application that's locking a file?](//stackoverflow.com/q/958123)

Comment: @DavidPostill Feel sorry,it hard for me to think out those Eglish,such as *locked file*..Anyway,think for your links.

Comment: If you delete the file with explorer in windows 10, it will actually tell you the name of the program that locks it in the error message.

Comment: @LPChip Yes,I find that,I just want to find it by powershell. :)

Answer (score 3):

1.[How to Find Out Which Windows Process is Using a File (Process Explorer)](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-find-out-which-windows-process-using-file.htm)

2.PowerShell method:

```
IF((Test-Path -Path $FileOrFolderPath) -eq $false) {
    Write-Warning "File or directory does not exist."       
}
Else {
    $LockingProcess = CMD /C "openfiles /query /fo table | find /I ""$FileOrFolderPath"""
    Write-Host $LockingProcess
}
```

3.[WhoLockMe Explorer Extension v2.0 beta (NT-Win2K-XP)](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/) - Explorer extension which adds a right-click menu option

Comment: First link doesn't work anymore ...